# If in where SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, if-statement, where-clause

I have a stored procedure which receives 10 parameters type Date but I can show the information when the consult have null because a have to show the flow of information of all the clients on this consult. Sometimes the client has orders with creditnotes but on occasions only have an order but not have Credit notes... 
I do this for the Where Clause:

```
        WHERE 
                (Customer.cd_CustomerID = ISNULL(@customer, Customer.cd_CustomerID))
                AND (@orderID IS NULL OR Orders.cd_OrderID = @orderID)
                AND (@Location IS NULL OR CustomerSL.cd_LocID = @Location)      
                and (Convert(date,Orders.fh_Date,111) BETWEEN coalesce (@FechaPedido1,'1900-01-01') AND  coalesce (@FechaPedido2,'3000-12-31' ))
                and (Convert(date,Receipt.fh_Date,111) BETWEEN coalesce (@FechaRemision1,'1900-01-01') AND  coalesce (@FechaRemision2,'3000-12-31' )) 
                and (Convert(date,Invoice.fh_Date,111) BETWEEN coalesce (@FechaFactura1,'1900-01-01') AND  coalesce (@FechaFactura2,'3000-12-31' )) 
                and (Convert(date,CreditNote.fh_Date,111) BETWEEN coalesce (@FechaNotaCredito1,'1900-01-01') AND  coalesce (@FechaNotaCredito2,'3000-12-31' ))
                and (Convert(date,Dispersion.fc_CreatedDate,111) BETWEEN coalesce (@FechaDispersion1,'1900-01-01') AND  coalesce (@FechaDispersion2,'3000-12-31' ))
```

But in this case, only show the information which has all the flow for the client. The consult doesn't show me the flow of information who doesn't have An order without remissions or Dispersion o whatever is the case...  already try with IF in Where but I have some problems with the syntax is...

> if (@fechapedido1 is  null)
>     begin
>   (Convert(date,Orders.fh_Date,111) BETWEEN  @FechaPedido1 and @FechaPedido2)
>     end

The SQL server shows me this message 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Convert'.'
but that line is correct... :S Please Help Me :D
thanks
:D

Comment: What is the ",111" in the date convert?  This looks like syntax to convert a date to an nvarchar... Try removing that.

Comment: the ",111" specify the format, it's fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have `IF` statements in a `WHERE` clause, try this:

```
AND 
(
    (
        @fechapedido1 is null AND 
        Convert(date,Orders.fh_Date,111) BETWEEN @FechaPedido1 and @FechaPedido2
    ) OR
    @fechapedido1 is not null 
)
```

Comment: If the lower limit `is null` then try comparing to it?  Perhaps that `AND` should have been an `OR`.

Comment: Good point, maybe they meant `if (@fechapedido1 is NOT null)`, otherwise that doesn't make sense. In that case, just flip them in the example above.

Comment: in my consult i do left join to present the information..but in occasions doesn't have a credit note for that client.. in the table credit note never has a Null for the date because when i assign a credit note automatically put a createdate on this register..